# Canonical for Python make/from_type classmethods/ multiple constructors?

Tags: discussion, canonical

There is no one single good canonical covering `make`/`from_<type>` classmethods/ multiple constructors in Python, and also Python has some language-design differences to Java/C/C++.
How should we create a good canonical?
Here are some which each address parts of this.

- [What is a clean, pythonic way to have multiple constructors in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682504/what-is-a-clean-pythonic-way-to-have-multiple-constructors-in-python)

  - *Where possible, it's Pythonic to overload `__init__()` with multiple arguments with default values=None and handling 'magic' cases inside the `__init__()` method*
- [How to overload __init__ method based on argument type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141545/how-to-overload-init-method-based-on-argument-type) / [Multiple constructors: the Pythonic way? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44765482/multiple-constructors-the-pythonic-way?noredirect=1&lq=1)

  - *Function overloading '__init__()` with multiple pass-by-name signatures (the Java way) having different argument types and number is not allowed*

    1. However you can use default parameters or **kwargs and *args arguments.
    2. Make staticmethods or classmethods with the @staticmethod or @classmethod decorator to return an instance of your class, or to add other constructors (`from_file`/`from_tuple`/...). But sometimes you can avoid this by introspecting on the argument types (is it a file? string-buffer? tuple?)
- [Multiple constructors in python? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164258/multiple-constructors-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [What is the difference between @staticmethod and @classmethod in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod-in-python)
- [Factory method for python object - best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14992474/factory-method-for-python-object-best-practice)

  - *Since there is less need for multiple constructors the Java way (`from_type1(), from_type2(),...`), there is less need in Python for factory methods, and often you can avoid them by using the above practices for a smarter `__init__()`*
- (still looking for good explanations of [when and where `__new__` is needed; for overriding defaults of builtin types, from classmethods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/why-is-init-always-called-after-new))

Comment: This is just a start, please help improve it. We're not currently serving the topic well esp. for people migrating from other languages.

Comment: If you downvote, or think this can be improved, then just say how. This is not great but it's already better and clearer than most answers on this topic.